# MGU - most general unifier for skolem functions?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, artificial-intelligence

I have trouble understanding MGU for functions, especially skolem functions.

Is it correct that in order to find MGU for 2 functions, say `f(x) and g(y)` then they must first of all be the same function ? `f = g`

I saw some solution comparing **2 skolem functions**: `R(x) = B(x)` where `R(x)` describes the room `x` is in and `B(x)` describes the building `x` is in. The statements were: `Visit(R(x)) and ~Visit(B(x))`.

**How could you possible unify 2 skolem functions** if they are basically functions and functions are considered as constants in the sense that they can't be compared unless equal? I mean we have no knowledge that R = B so how can we state that R(x) = B(x) ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unify $f(x)$ and $g(y)$.

We have a *substitution*, i.e. a finite set of the form $\{ t_1/v_1,\ldots,t_n/v_n \ \}$, where every $v_i$ is a variable, and every $t_i$ is a term.

A subst $\theta = \{ t_1/v_1,\ldots,t_n/v_n \ \}$ acts on an expression $E$ and $E \theta$ is the expression obtained from $E$ by replacing  simultaneously each occurrence of the variable $v_i$ with term $t_i$.

A substitution $\theta$ is called a *unifier* for a set $\{ E_1,\ldots,E_k \}$ iff $E_1 \theta= E_2 \theta = \ldots = E_k \theta$. The set $\{ E_1,\ldots,E_k \}$ is said to be *unifiable* if there is a unifier for it.

Comment: So does that basically mean that unification of functions (whether skolem functions or regular) is allowed only if: 1) It's exactly the same function and 2) No other contradiction occurs due to arguments of function ?

But contidition 1 must always hold, yes ?

Comment: @caffein - you unify formulas and not function letters. Having said that, an unifier is a subst of variables with terms. Consider e.g. the formula $f(x)=g/y)$; there is no way to subst $x$ and $y$ with terms whatever such that the leading $f$ (or $g$) disappear.