# Most General unifier in logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, substitution

i have a question about most general unifier in logic. i'll begin by saying that in the class we were only given a summary in a few words, without any example, and they just moved on to the next topic and left us wondering on how to solve it, so i am trying based on what i've learnt from reading here:

i need to find the MGU, if it exists, for every pair of atomic propositions.

1)$Q(one, two, two)$ ,  $Q(x,y,z)$

2)$R(x,F(A,B)$ , $R(F(y,y),x)$

my attempt:

1)not exist because Two is written twice and we can't use substitution so that it will have two different meanings.

2)$R(F(x,B), F(A,B)), R(F(y,y),F(x,B))$

is it correct? would really appreciate your assistance and correction with this. thank you very much

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172973/mgu-most-general-unifier-for-skolem-functions) for the def of *unifier*.

Comment: The subst : $x \leftarrow \text {one}, y \leftarrow \text {two}, z \leftarrow \text {two}$ will work.

Comment: and for the second? meanwhile i am trying to find also explanations on youtube and worked examples to learn how to apply the theory correctly

Comment: Similar; see the def in the linked post. A *subst* is an operation of replacing *terms* in place of *variables*. Thus, start with $A$ and $B$ in place of $y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the second should be $/theta = [F(y,y)/x, a/x,b/x]$ ?

Comment: NO; there is no subst that can "reproduce F(A,B) from F(y,y).